# codeigniter join query for same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, codeigniter-2

I have a table structure for user order into various shop like below. Now I want to get the query will be in codeigniter

1. Select list of shop_id belongs to the user_id
2. Select the list of products then belongs to the shop_id and user_id
3. Then it will comes into one single array.

Like this : Please give me a query for this.I have tried separate functions but i need one single functions using join's

`` user_id
    ->  shop_id
        ->      products
            [0] ->product_name1
            [1] -> product_name2` ``

```
Table : at_order
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
| id | user_id    | shop_id   | product-id |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+
|  1 | 3          | 3         |          32|
|  2 | 3          | 3         |          24|
|  3 | 3          | 4         |          3 |
|  4 | 4          | 3         |          8 |
|  5 | 4          | 5         |          4 |
|  6 | 4          | 6         |          1 |
+----+------------+-----------+------------+

function main () 
{
    SELECT
      `shop_id`
    FROM (`at_order`)
    WHERE `user_id` = '3'
    GROUP BY `shop_id`;
    one($shop_id,$user_id);

}

function one () 
{
    SELECT
      `product_id`,
      `order_status`
    FROM (`at_order`)
    WHERE `user_id` = '3'
        AND `shop_id` = '5';
    two($shop_id,$product_id);
}

function two () 
{
    SELECT *
    FROM (`at_product`)
    WHERE `product_id` = '35'
        AND `shop_id` = '5'
}
```

I have write these three queries in three functions and join this functions in main functions

```
Please help
```

Comment: can you clearify your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a single query that only need user id and will fetch all the required things.

```
function getUserProducts($user_id){

    $query  =   "SELECT
                    as.shop_name,
                    ap.*
                FROM at_order ao
                LEFT JOIN at_product ap 
                    ON ap.product_id = ao.product_id
                LEFT JOIN at_shops as
                    ON as.shop_id = ao.shop_id
                WHERE ao.user_id = $user_id";
    return $this->db->query($query)->result_array();

    //Or Active Record Version

    return $this->db
                ->select('ao.shop_name')
                ->select('ap.*')
                ->from('at_order ao')
                ->join('at_product ap ','ap.product_id = ao.product_id','left')
                ->join('at_shops as','as.shop_id = ao.shop_id','left')
                ->where('ao.user_id',$user_id)
                ->get()
                ->result_array();
}
```